# Firestore onSnapshot() is being called on getDocs(). how to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My expectation is to observe the changes of my collection only when there is a WRITE/DELETE action. By doing some search I understood onSnapshot() method does that. But this method unexpectedly is being called when I'm reading my documents by getDocs().
Here is my code:

```
// Firestore instance is defined and collection reference is accessible

const db = getFirestore();
const todosCollection = collection(db, 'todos');

// For the sake of testing I even tried to stop the observer at the fetch method by using a boolean variable
let areTodosFetched = false;

function onTodosChange() {
    if (!areTodosFetched) {
      console.log('should return');
      return;
    }
    onSnapshot(todosCollection, (snapShot) => {
      snapShot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          // The code drops in this block!
          console.log('New todo: ', change.doc.id);
        }
        if (change.type === 'modified') {
          console.log('Modified todo: ', change.doc.id);
        }
        if (change.type === 'removed') {
          console.log('Removed todo: ', change.doc.id);
        }
      });
    });
  }


async function getTodos() {
    try {
      await getDocs(todosCollection);
      areTodosFetched = true;
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting documents: ', error);
    }
  }


// In a component I'm executing them
await getTodos();
onTodosChange();
```

I removed all side effects of getTodos() method and I'm only calling `await getDocs(todosCollection);`

But still the observer is being called.

Comment: `onSnapshot` will fires right away when you attach it with the current state of the query or collection you attach it to. If you want to only get documents that are added/updated after you attach the listener, you'll need to add `createdAt`/`updatedAt` fields to your documents, set those with the correct values, and then [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to only listen for updates that happen after a certain timestamp.

Comment: Well explained! Thanks. I will give it a shot

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
A query as below works for observing the upcoming documents.
`const upcomingTodos = query(todosCollection, where('modifiedTime', '>', Date.now()));`
But then I wonder, how can I write a query to observe all documents that are being deleted?
And my second question is, does snapshot come with a prop that let me know the change is made by remote or current client? 
Thanks!

Comment: For monitoring document deletion, you'll want to not actually delete the document but keep a so-called tombstone doc. For example: delete all regular data fields from the document, and add an `deletedAt` instead.